# Using a db string as a query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am making a list activity that will contain 'achievements'.  Each achievement is a record in a sqlite db in the app.  In each record, I have a column with a query string stored.  For each record in the db, I am using the query string against another user generated db to determine which achievements have been accomplished...

The query strings I have been using are working correctly in my sqlite manager program... however in my app, it appears that the query is being ignored and returns the entire user generated db.  I'm sure there is the potential for other general errors (like null query string returned etc) but I couldn't find any, and right now I don't have my code here to post.

**Are there any pitfalls I am falling into by executing a query from a string extracted from the achievement db?**  This was the most straightforward way I could envision doing the achievements without a whole lot of if-then clauses.

EDIT: In the end I found an error in the call, passing the wrong argument.  Pitfall in the end was working too bleary-eyed.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your data is denormalised.  This makes it harder to change, if you ever need to change the format for example.  It will also be harder to do a variety of things with your data, e.g. query the number of people with a given achievement.

Comment: Since I will be performing the query from my app db on the user generated data I will continue as is; any changes will only require an upgrade on the app db.